# Convert string to date in google big query

Tags: date, datetime, google-bigquery, date-conversion

I have a string column which has date value in the below format

6/1/2020 12:00:00 AM

I want only the date part and convert the column to date
so when i use date_trunc and parse date like below it is giving error

select CAST(DATE_TRUNC(PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', datecolumn), AS DATE)) from table name

PLease let me know what is the best way to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Use below

```
select date(parse_datetime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p', datecolumn))
from your_table
```